# Can I use the recent c# addition 'case when' clause to use StartsWith in a switch?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

`case when` is fairly new so many answers don't touch upon it. The MSDN example is about casting the object, not using the original string.

```
switch (catName)
{
    case string c when c.StartsWith("Fluffy"):
        // DoSomething
        break;
}
```

This seems to work, it'd be nicer if you could omit the `string c` part and just do `when catName` instead. But then multiple cases don't work:

```
switch (catName)
{
    case string c when c.StartsWith("Fluffy"):
    case string c when c.StartsWith("Mr"):
        // DoSomething
        break;
}
```

Because you can't declare two `string c`. So you could change the second one, but you'd end up with a list of string a, string b, string c etc which doesn't seem very nice.

The ideal way would of course be something like:

```
switch (catName)
{
    case when catName.StartsWith("Fluffy"):
        ...
        break;
}
```

Is there an elegant way to solve this, or is it simply better to use an `if..else if` method?

Comment: No you cant do that, and the other examples are a kind of Frankenstein switch by pattern matching. You would save more readable characters with if then else. you could use a  `List<(Func<string, bool> func, Action action)>()` and  `list.Where(x => x.func(someValue));` but even worse IMO

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find a comprehensive answer involving a method call.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

My favourite solution is suggested by kofifus in the comments:

```cs
    string catName = "Fluffy";
    switch (catName)
    {
        case {} when catName.StartsWith("Fluffy"):
        case {} when catName.StartsWith("Mr"):
            Console.WriteLine(catName);
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Name does not start with Mr or Fluffy.");
            break;
    }
```

I know you said two different strings isn't nice, but this looks very readable to me, is there really a problem with doing it like this:

```
    string catName = "Fluffy";
    switch (catName)
    {
        case string c when c.StartsWith("Fluffy"):
        case string d when d.StartsWith("Mr"):
            Console.WriteLine(catName); 
            break;  
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Name does not start with Mr or Fluffy.");  
            break;  
    }
```

Alternatively, based on the 'Reference' link in Krustys answer you could do it like this:

```
    string catName = "Noodle";
    switch (catName)
    {
        case string c when (c.StartsWith("Fluffy") || c.StartsWith("Mr")):
            Console.WriteLine(catName); 
            break;  
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Name does not begin with Mr or Fluffy.");    
            break;  
    }
```

Comment: you can do `{}` instead of `string c` ie `case {} when ... catName.StartsWith(...`

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, because you are using [the pattern matching into the switch statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#type-pattern) and the type is evaluated at compile time:

> expr has a compile-time type that is a base class of type

Anyway, you can use the same variable names because their scope is local. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#-the-case-statement-and-the-when-clause)